# Expansion and factoring with trig identities.

Tags: calculus

I have a question about this expansion..

Lets say I have $(\cos u + i\sin u）^2$ and after expanding, we get $\cos^2 u +2i\sin u\cos u + i^2\sin^2u$. However  what if we have $\cos u 2i\sin u$ instead, which one is correct?

Since in the expansion we get cosuisinu and isinucosu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the difference? Basically, you are asking whether $(a+bc)^2$ is equal to $$a^2 + (2b)ac + b^2c^2$$
or $$a_2+b(2c)a + b^2c^2.$$

As you probably know, multiplication is commutative and associative so $(2b)ac = (2b)(ac) = (b\cdot 2)(ca) = b\cdot(2(ca)) = b((2c)a) = b(2c)a.$

Comment: I'm sorry , I just made edit to question and took out brackets since its confusing because 2i is attached to sin..

Comment: @user3718584 My asnwer still stands. All you are asking is whether multiplication is commutative. $\cos u \cdot i \cdot \sin u = i\cdot \sin u\cdot \cos u$.

Comment: Okay right, so for the trig identity cosu2sinu is same as 2sinucosu and both equal sin2u?

Comment: @user3718584 do you know that in general, $abc=bac$?

Comment: Yes, but i just assumed that maybe it doesnt extend to trig identities and that those two might yield diff values but i was wrong.

Comment: @user3718584 Forget about trig identities. $\sin u$ is a number. A complex number, maybe, but a number. Let's call it $x$. And $\cos u$ is also a number. Call it $y$. Then $xiy=ixy=xyi=\dots$ any ordering works.